# How to divide a list into more lists in a generated admin backend?

Tags: list, symfony1, doctrine

I am pretty new in symfony. I am using symfony 1.4 and I already set up my backend for my project saving some articles.

However, In my article edit view, I have a list, with a many to many relationship to the article filters. I have an enumeration in the filters table, to give the filters 3 types. (there will be only 3, that's why I didnt created 3 Filters tables)

Here my doctrine schema, so you can imagine it.

```
    detect_relations: true
      Article:
        columns:
          article_no:          { type: string(50), notnull: true }
          producer:            { type: string(100) }
          name:                { type: string(255), notnull: true }
          description:         { type: string(2000) }
        attributes:
          export: all
          validate: true

    Filter:
      columns:
        name:  { type: string(255) }
        type:  { type: enum, values: ['Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3']}
      relations:
        Article:
          foreignAlias: Filters
          class: Article
          refClass: FilterArticle

    FilterArticle:
      columns:
        filter_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
        article_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
      relations:
        Filter: { foreignAlias: FilterArticle }
        Article: { foreignAlias: FilterArticle }
```

So in my Edit View, I have a big list with the filters.
But I want to divide this list into these 3 different types and display 3 lists.

Is this possible ? How can i realize that ? I suppose I need to overwrite the ArticleForm or FilterForm ?! Or can I do it only configuring the generator?

THank you all for the help, I can only say I love symfony :)

greetings

Comment: looking for similar : I want to list page into two by status field. pending article needs to be list separate and active article needs to be separate.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see here is, that you want to change the way the list view is rendered.
i assume that you have already created your admin auto-generated module.

if you go to your appropriate cache dir for your environment and go to templates, you should find a `_list.php` file, this partial holds the table display html/php and you should see the logic that iterates through the results, eg:

```
foreach ($pager->getResults()...
```

copy this `_list.php` to your auto generated module's templates dir..
here you can custom edit this file to override how the list view is rendered and add extra logic to distinguish how your 3 lists render...